# Git displays missing/corrupt files and will not allow commit

Tags: git

When I try to commit to my git vcs, I get the following

```
error: f5f1344a1b5087625adb898e960924f4fd7e3872: invalid sha1 pointer in cache-tree
broken link from    tree 0f4c776b680905e4a46068e2b7753296150ce58c
              to    tree 2a0aaaee384ebd7e58ebae7bd11d5a426e586ba7
missing tree 2a0aaaee384ebd7e58ebae7bd11d5a426e586ba7
dangling blob 50e08c2477f52756077620ad9c28b5d0f435ead4
dangling blob a12229257dc6e434dbced13a3674a890c53b9175
dangling blob b43eb25556ba82264a076a9e1ff89c985af34bef
dangling blob e9e4bc52fafbfcbc114edfb16d0aa7e0405867fa
dangling blob 0b838b25379fd81df73ba1b268121b7b2dd0c8b0
dangling blob 33d31e0b2a204949318cfbcba002d42f3f507862
dangling blob 4187a4ee1c721fe84ca07e705af53a32693b92c3
missing blob 5e6749b536143ec528c1c60a34ddcf8e9f810fd3
dangling blob 6635f71f039673dc2d618496b82d244c26af38e2
dangling blob a2d57e631e17ee9b790d0db4cb1a816d6d6b5d3a
dangling blob d8b513437a8f40df24b6684a37d7b67cbc8d07ec
error: d7af69ae99ef8385e8b7ccdc899ac56290fbdd91: invalid sha1 pointer in cache-tree
```

Is there a way for me to correct this to allow commit?
Or do I have to create a new git repo?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you local repo is corrupted. Is there any downside to trying to clone from your origin again? and then apply changes on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned here](http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-03/msg00011.html)

> "bad object" is about an object that did not parse correctly, as opposed
>   to one that is missing. So it's possible that your repository is
>   corrupted.
>
> I'm not up on the latest techniques for verifying and fixing corruption.
>   But I think with recent enough git, you can grab a good copy of the
>   object from another repo and put it in

```
.git/objects/c9/ee57c5c20c3b7a2d7784a4172aef8b34c3a844
```

> that git would do the right thing.

Still, I would as commented try and clone again the remote repo in a new path, and report my modifications (without history though) with:

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/first/corrupted/repo add .
git commit -m "import local changes"
```